# NextJS beta App router. GET request fails with fetch but works with browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Im using nextJS with the APP dir and am having this issue with doing a GET request...

I have the following function to getProjects from my /project route.ts.

It seems like its not triggering the GET function within my routes.ts

console.log("in GET /projects"), is never triggered, and i get an unexpected end of JSON error.

However if I visit "http://localhost:3000/api/project" in the browser it does hit the GET function in my routes.ts and i get the JSON back...

Thanks for any help, Ive been on this for a while...

```
export const projectsGet = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/project", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  console.log(res, 'before')     //triggers
  const data = await res.json()  // error: Unexpected end of JSON input
  console.log(data, 'after')     // does not trigger
  
  return data
};
```

This is my project route, in /api/project/route.ts.  I have a POST route in the same file which creates a project and works fine...

```
export const GET = async () => {
  console.log("in GET /projects");  //never triggers unless i visit the URL in browser

  const user = await getUserFromCookie(cookies());

  const projects = await db.project.findMany({
    where: {
      ownerId: user?.id,
    },
    include: {
      tasks: true,
    },
  });

  const filteredProjects = projects.filter((project) => {
    return project.deleted === false;
  });

  return NextResponse.json(filteredProjects);
};
```

Comment: Why are you setting a content-type header for a GET request?

Comment: since it works when you visit the url on browser, that means `route.ts` `GET` works. you most likely not call the `projectsGet`. or your `url` inside function is not correct

Comment: Where and when are you calling `projectsGet()`?

Comment: within a async server page component.

  const allProjects = await projectsGet();

Comment: Also I am copy pasting the url from my fetch function into the browser so the URL is correct.  and my app crashes until i comment out  const allProjects = await projectsGet();

Comment: you need fetch it from your server component... await fetch("/api/path/to/route").then(r => r.json())

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return the json in this form in `/api/project/route.ts.

```
export async function GET(){
  console.log("in GET /projects");

  const user = await getUserFromCookie(cookies());

  const projects = await db.project.findMany({
    where: {
      ownerId: user?.id,
    },
    include: {
      tasks: true,
    },
  });

  const filteredProjects = projects.filter((project) => {
    return project.deleted === false;
  });

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(filteredProjects));
};
```